# HTTP REDIRECT(3xx) TO A DIFFERENT HOST

Tags: http, tcp, embedded

I'm building a HTTP client(for embedded devices) and I was wondering,
If I receive a HTTP 3xx response, and in the location header I get a hostname different from the one I had in the request. Should I disconnect the TCP connection and reconnect to the new host, or I just need to send a new request with a new host header and keep the old TCP connection alive. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to reuse the original TCP connection if you're being redirected elsewhere. If my webserver only hosts `example.com` and I redirect you to `elsewhere.net`, my webserver will probably not respond to a request for `elsewhere.net`.

Worse, this also potentially sets you up for a great man-in-the-middle attack if my server redirects you to `http://bank.com` and you reuse the same TCP connection when sending a request to `bank.com`. My server can maliciously respond to requests with `Host: bank.com`, which isn't something you want to happen.

You can't assume the original connection can be reused unless the redirect is to the same same host with the same protocol.

Persistent HTTP connections are a little tricky with the number of client/server combinations. You can avoid the complexity by just wasting time closing and re-establishing each connection:

- If you're implementing a HTTP/1.0 client, `Connection: keep-alive` isn't something you have to implement. Compliant servers should just close the connection after every request if you don't negotiate that you support persistent connections.
- If you're implementing a HTTP/1.1 client and don't want to persist the connection, just send `Connection: close` with your request and a HTTP/1.1 server should close the connection.

Comment: So if for example I'm trying to send GET request to HTTP://www.google.com/ and it responds with status code 302 and location header to HTTP://www.google.de/. I need to disconnect the TCP and reconnect to google.de? And then send a new get request?

Comment: @A.Boy: Yes. What else can you do?

Comment: I don't know ,maybe they are the same server behind those two URLs, no?

Comment: what about 3xx response codes which are temporary and not permanent?  Do I need to: 1. Close TCP 2. Connect to the new host I received via location header  in the 3xx response and send the request . And for the next requests I'll send,  do I need to close the TCP and start new TCP connection with the original host before the 3xx response?

Comment: @A.Boy: You can't assume that they are hosted by the same server (you would have to check by comparing the DNS records). Why would you connect again to the original host if you were redirected elsewhere?

Comment: Thats's what I'm asking , the spec define that there are temporary redirects Wich you shouldnt save the location redirect for next request , and there are permanent which you should always address the new location. For example return code 301 vs 302. Temporary return code you need to connect to new host then close the connection and reconnect to the original for the next request

Comment: @A.Boy: For permanent redirects, all you should do is keep a cache that maps `original_url → new_url` and every time you encounter `original_url`, you can just send your request instead to `new_url` (see the RFC for exceptions). You don't *have* to treat permanent and temporary redirects any differently in your code (the RFC says "ought to", not "MUST"), but it's just natural to cache the permanent redirect so you don't have to ask the server again if it already told you the redirect was permanent. For an embedded client, I don't think the overhead of caching permanent redirects is needed.